# How to improve problem solving skills while unemployed?

Tags: websites, portfolio

I graduated from the university where I learned mathematics, computer science, statistics and physics. It was really nice to solve problems and optimize things. How can I improve my problem solving skills while I'm unemployed? I mean, is there some kind of website where is problems with various difficulty levels and one can build portfolio by solving those, and maybe some discussion forum about how to improve existence solutions?

Comment: Afraid this isn't really a workplace question, and it's also rather broad and open-ended, so not a great fit for this site.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to improve your problem solving skills this way? The "normal" way would be after university to land a job (which sounds quite doable with your education) and improve your skills there. The bonus is that you get paid to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough rep to leave a comment, but off the top of my head:

- Kaggle (quite difficult, real world problems; IMHO best way to build genuine skill)
- Any number of programming puzzle question sites, like Hackerrank; these are geared more towards interview style questions
- Code Review Stack Exchange is quite good for the discussion element of your question; you can get good, in depth feedback on relatively small bits of code